# Curl Post with File

Tags: bash, curl

I have data phone in phone.txt

> +6285712341234
>   +6285712341235
>   +6285712341236
>   +6285712341237
>   +6285712341238

but I don't know how to use this data to curl, here's what I tried:

> curl -X POST "https://rest-api.moceansms.com/rest/1/sms" -d "mocean-api-key={api_key}&mocean-api-secret={api_secret}&mocean-from={name}&mocean-to={phone.txt}&mocean-text=Hello"

I should use phone data to send SMS to everyone; I googled for a solution, but with no luck (I don't even know whether the keywords I used to look for a solution where correct or not).

Answer (score 1):

You should use --data flag:

Check:

1. https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2007-03/0097.html
2. https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d

Here the entire explanation from man:

> -d, --data
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server,
>   in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML
>   form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the
>   data to the server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F, --form.
>
> --data-raw is almost the same but does not have a special interpretation of the @ character. To post data purely binary, you
>   should instead use the --data-binary option. To URL-encode the value
>   of a form field you may use --data-urlencode.
>
> If any of these options is used more than once on the same command
>   line, the data pieces specified will be merged together with a
>   separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would
>   generate a post chunk that looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.
>
> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file
>   name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data
>   from stdin. Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a
>   file named 'foobar' would thus be done with -d, --data @foobar. When
>   --data is told to read from a file like that, carriage returns and newlines will be stripped out. If you don't want the @ character to
>   have a special interpretation use --data-raw instead.
>
> See also --data-binary and --data-urlencode and --data-raw. This
>   option overrides -F, --form and -I, --head and --upload.